# Upload file to server directory in spring-hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working on Spring hibernate project I want to upload file to server directory.   If I save file to a directory manually specified the file is successfully uploaded to the path specified. but I want a path so that when I upload my project to cloud i need not make any changes.

I tried "user.dir" but it gives me path where I have my STS installed. but I dont want this path.

My contoller is attached below

```
public class FileUploadController {
@Autowired
private FileUploadDAO fileUploadDao;


@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload/*,@PathVariable("student_id") long student_id*/) throws Exception {

    if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
        for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload){

             String orginalName=aFile.getOriginalFilename();

            System.out.println("Saving file: " + orginalName);          


            File currentDirFile = new File(".");
            String helper = currentDirFile.getAbsolutePath();
            helper = helper.substring(0, helper.length()-1);
            System.out.println("helper : "+helper);



        String path= request.getServletContext().getInitParameter(helper);

        System.out.println("path : "+path);



            String path1=request.getServletContext().getContextPath();

            String finalPath=path1+File.separator+"src"+File.separator+"main"+File.separator+"webapp"+File.separator+"img"+File.separator;

            String f1=helper+finalPath;

            System.out.println("f1 : "+f1);

        File file = new File(finalPath);
        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println(path1);
            System.out.println("finalPath : "+finalPath);


            if (!file.exists()) {
                if (file.mkdir()) {
                    System.out.println("Directory is created!");

                    String filePath = finalPath+"/"+orginalName;
                    File destination = new File(filePath);
                    //  fileUploadDao.savePath(filePath);
                            String status ="success";

                    try {
                       aFile.transferTo(destination);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        status="failure";
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        status="iofailure";
                    }



            System.out.println(filePath);
            fileUploadDao.save(filePath); 
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
        }else{

            System.out.println("Directory is already exist!");

            String filePath = finalPath+orginalName;

            System.out.println("filePath : "+filePath);




            File destination = new File(f1);


            String status ="success";

            try {
               aFile.transferTo(destination);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                status="failure";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                status="iofailure";
            }


    System.out.println(filePath);

    fileUploadDao.save(filePath); 
    //  }


        }
    }

    //return "Success";
}
```

Comment: So you want to save all the files under the current User directory ? Correct

Comment: yeah..but current directory(using (user.dir) or only (.)) shows me STS installed directory. I even tried to save to img directory in my webapp but it  gives exception of path not found

Comment: if i check path of img directory's path it shows same path of STS

Comment: what is the server you are using ? to deploy . The reason is its taking the sever path . can you confirm the server in inside the STS installation folder

Comment: I am using apache tomcat. I didn't get what u mean by ''can you confirm the server in inside the STS installation folder " Plz elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Update :

In AWS/Online you will have a folder(or Create One) say `myAppUploadedFiles` in a route directory or where you have the access . `mkdir /myAppUploadedFiles` . now in your local you can give like this `/myAppUploadedFiles/folder` . it will create a folder in `c:/myAppUploadedFiles/folderName` . It will work in both envorionment.

> This is how it works in production environment , what we do is we keep all files under `opt\AppFiles` folder . For development you just create a `C:\opt\AppFiles folder` .

Here using `/` will take the system  path  `File file = new File("/myAppUploadedFiles/folderName");`

The updated code which is platform independent ,

```
package com.company.test;

import java.io.File;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World.");
        System.out.println("User name "+System.getProperty("user.name"));
        File file = new File("/myAppUploadedFiles/folderName");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (file.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: as I earlier mentioned if I manually create a directory in C:\ drive or any other location and specify that path in ...new FILE(path).. but how will it work when I upload my project on AWS. I have to make project online later and where will the files get stored when uploaded from different machines

Comment: thanks for your valuable feedback..ill check if this works

Answer (score 0):

You should use a property so that your code is decoupled from the operating system specifics.

`@Value("${file.uploads.folder}")
private String fileUploadsFolder;`

In your main configuration class (assuming Java config here) you then specify the property source file.

`@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties"})
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
@Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}`

Then for each environment (e.g. dev, prod) you can use the spring profiles feature and create an application-XXXX.properties file for each each spring profile (subsitute XXXX with the name of the profile).  Within this file you can specify the path.

application-dev.properties:

`file.uploads.folder=C:/temp/uploadFolder`

application-prod.properties:

`file.uploads.folder=/var/uploadFolder`

When you startup the JVM don't forget to specify the spring profile you want to run by adding the system argument -Dspring.profiles.active=XXXX